# Log4j2 export XML configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

In my project I need to load a "default" log4j2 XML configuration, then modify it and then save it in order to reload on next opening.

I found how to modify the configuration but I didn't find how to generate the XML from the configuration.

```
final LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();

// changes here...

// generate XML file & save it from the config
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't. I postponed to the future